# Tomcat 6 error while deploying spring war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc, war

I am trying to deploy my war on tomcat 6.I have copied my `war` to `/usr/local/tomcat6/weapps` directory.
However browsing to `localhost:8080/my-app`
gives me this error:

```
type Exception report

message Cannot construct Factory : com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory.<init>(com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.Config)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Cannot construct Factory : com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory.<init>(com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.Config)
    com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.Factory.getInstance(Factory.java:53)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.initContentProcessor(SiteMeshFilter.java:107)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Can anybody give me some idea where I'm missing something?
My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.vantage.flip-club</groupId>
  <artifactId>flip-club</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Flip Club</name>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <scm>
    <connection>
    scm:svn:svn://svn.vantage.com/digitalsports/filp-club/trunk
    </connection>
    <developerConnection>
    scm:svn:svn://svn.vantage.com/digitalsports/filp-club/trunk
    </developerConnection>
    <url>http://svn.vantage.com/websvn2/listing.php?repname=DigitalSports+Repository</url>
  </scm>

  <properties>


    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


    <vantage.vlibrary.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</vantage.vlibrary.version>


    <commons-lang3.version>3.1</commons-lang3.version>
    <commons-httpclient.version>3.1</commons-httpclient.version>


    <springframework.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>


    <crowd.version>2.7.0</crowd.version>


    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
    <javax-el.version>2.2</javax-el.version>
    <jaxb-impl.version>2.2.7</jaxb-impl.version>


    <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>


    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>


    <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
    <ehcache.version>2.6.5</ehcache.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.2-1002.jdbc4</postgresql.version>


    <jackson-asl.version>1.9.12</jackson-asl.version>
    <json-taglib.version>0.4.1</json-taglib.version>


    <sitemesh.version>2.4.2</sitemesh.version>
    <packtag.version>3.8</packtag.version>


    <logback.version>1.0.12</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>


    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jsp.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${jaxb-impl.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define
      this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
      <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BEGIN: Crowd Libraries -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
      <artifactId>embedded-crowd-api</artifactId>
      <version>${crowd.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
      <artifactId>crowd-integration-api</artifactId>
      <version>${crowd.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
      <artifactId>crowd-integration-client-common</artifactId>
      <version>${crowd.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
      <artifactId>crowd-integration-client-rest</artifactId>
      <version>${crowd.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
      <artifactId>crowd-integration-client-soap</artifactId>
      <version>${crowd.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
      <artifactId>crowd-integration-springsecurity</artifactId>
      <version>${crowd.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-aegis</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- END: Crowd Libraries -->

    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
      <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON Utilities -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-asl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-asl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atg</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
      <version>${json-taglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Web Utilities -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
      <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
      <version>${sitemesh.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>packtag</groupId>
      <artifactId>packtag</artifactId>
      <version>${packtag.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lexipedia http client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.5</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Rest Client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>us.monoid.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>resty</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Packaging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Vantage VLibrary Client -->
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>vlibrary-module-embedded-client</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.vantage</groupId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <finalName>${war.finalName}</finalName>

    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/${env.resources.dir}</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/common</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>${server.url}</url>
          <server>${server.id}</server>
          <path>${server.context}</path>
          <update>${webapp.update}</update>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <repositories>

    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>

    <pluginRepository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>

  </pluginRepositories>

  <distributionManagement>
    <!--use the following if you ARE NOT deploying a snapshot version. -->
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Vantage Nexus Release Repository</name>
      <url>
      http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/repositories/vantage-release
      </url>
    </repository>
    <!--use the following if you ARE deploying a snapshot version. -->
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus-snapshot</id>
      <name>Vantage Nexus Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>
      http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/repositories/vantage-snapshot
      </url>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <!-- USAGE: tomcat7:deploy -Penv-development-flip-club  --> 
      <id>env-development-flip-club</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>development-flip-club</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <env.resources.dir>development</env.resources.dir>
        <!-- NOTE: This server url is for tomcat 7 -->
        <server.url>http://localhost:8686/manager/text</server.url>
        <server.context>/flip-club</server.context>
        <server.id>iseek-web</server.id>
        <webapp.update>true</webapp.update>
        <war.finalName>flip-club</war.finalName>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <!-- USAGE: tomcat7:deploy -Penv-staging-flip-club  --> 
      <id>env-staging-flip-club</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>staging-flip-club</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <env.resources.dir>staging</env.resources.dir>
        <!-- NOTE: This server url is for tomcat 7 -->
        <server.url>http://192.168.8.18:8686/manager/text</server.url>
        <server.context>/flip-club</server.context>
        <server.id>iseek-web</server.id>
        <webapp.update>true</webapp.update>
        <war.finalName>flip-club</war.finalName>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <!-- USAGE: tomcat7:deploy -Penv-production-flip-club  --> 
      <id>env-production-flip-club</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>production-flip-club</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <env.resources.dir>production</env.resources.dir>
        <!-- NOTE: This server url is for tomcat 7 -->
        <server.url>http://192.168.16.149:8080/manager/text</server.url>
        <server.context>/</server.context>
        <server.id>iseek-web</server.id>
        <webapp.update>true</webapp.update>
        <war.finalName>flip-club</war.finalName>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

</project>
```

**Edit:**
I still wonder why this happended because of not doing `chmod a+x` with `tomcat` dir.

Comment: Looks like you've got a version mismatch between what's in your WAR and what Spring expects for Sitemesh.

Comment: I think that you have conflicts with .jars . can you put you pom.xml?

Comment: @Makoton: I have edited my question.Please see my pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting thing is that doing :

```
chmod a+x tomcatdir/
```

and restarting `tomcat` did solve my problem :)

Comment: I can't explain why the ```chmod``` makes thing work (see *UPDATE* in my answer) but I'm happy you have solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of the jar containing `com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory` and be sure that is compatible with the version that your Spring jars require.

**UPDATE**

I can't explain why the `chmod` makes thing work.

The exception is thrown from [Factory.getInstance](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/opensymphony/sitemesh/2.2.1/com/opensymphony/module/sitemesh/Factory.java#Factory.getInstance%28com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.Config%29) so the exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`, encapsuled into an `com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException`, might be thrown by the absence of a default constructor in a class extending  `Config` class.

Comment: I forgot to `chmod a+x` tomcat dir and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error is more with your integration Sitemesh with Spring.

maybe this can help you:
https://github.com/JVerstry/Web-Related-Examples/tree/master/Spring-Sitemesh-Integration/

Comment: Actually, I forgot doing `chmod a+x tomcatdir/` and now everything works fine :)